# My Javascript don't work. I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
  <title>Floza Web Design | Conception web</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav" id="nav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close" class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times</a>
      <a href="#">Accueil</a>
      <a href="#">Réalisations</a>
      <a href="#">Notre équipe</a>
      <a href="#">Nos services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <span id="open" class="open" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     fonction openNav(){
       document.getElementsById('open').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementsById('nav').style.width = "100%";
       }
     fonction closeNav(){
       document.getElementsById('nav').style.width = "0";
       document.getElementsById('open').style.display = "block";
     }
    </script>
</header>
  <div class="div"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong ? i want to make my menu appear full page and it does not work. I'm new to Javascript. I follow a youtube video STEP BY STEP and it don't work.

Thanks

Comment: Try `function` with a `u` not `fonction`

Comment: OMG. The basic french to english mistake. Im feel terrible right now xD

Comment: Back to the good 'ol syntax errors. ;)

Comment: For the future, "it does not work" is not a useful problem statement. In this case, for example, you would have seen a syntax error on the console. Next time you ask a question, please tell *how* something is not working.

Comment: I take note. But now, i change the syntaxe but the menu still not appear on click. any idea ?

Comment: All your problems should have caused error messages in the console log. Didn't you see those messages?

Comment: And if you use a good IDE, it should also notice these typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It needs to be f**u**nction, not f**o**nction
- It's getElementById, not getElement**s**ById (mind the plural here, it has to be singular)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
  <title>Floza Web Design | Conception web</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav" id="nav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close" class="close" onclick="closeNav()">&times</a>
      <a href="#">Accueil</a>
      <a href="#">Réalisations</a>
      <a href="#">Notre équipe</a>
      <a href="#">Nos services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <span id="open" class="open" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function openNav(){
       document.getElementById('open').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('nav').style.width = "100%";
       }
     function closeNav(){
       document.getElementById('nav').style.width = "0";
       document.getElementById('open').style.display = "block";
     }
    </script>
</header>
  <div class="div"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @NicolasBoulianne Glad to help! Please consider marking the anwer as the one that helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have misspelled the word "function".
Your code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 fonction openNav(){
   document.getElementsById('open').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementsById('nav').style.width = "100%";
   }
 fonction closeNav(){
   document.getElementsById('nav').style.width = "0";
   document.getElementsById('open').style.display = "block";
 }
</script>
```

Correct the spelling to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function....
 function....
</script>
```

Also, you appear to have misspelled getElementsById()
There is no "s".  The correct spelling is getElementById()

May I suggest you download a good code editor such as Visual Code.
It is free.
It will catch your misspellings.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes to take care of first:

1. "fonction" should be "function"
2. "document.getElementsById" should be "document.getElementById" ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById))
3. The functions are not defined when you try to do the onclick, I'd recommend setting up event listeners for those elements separately in the javascript rather than inlining the function

Example would be something along the lines of:

```
document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('nav').style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById('open').style.display = "block";
})

document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('open').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('nav').style.width = "100%";
})
```

You can also create a javascript file separately to manage all these functions and reference the file either in the  tag or after the  tag depending on when you need it to load.

In this file I recommend setting up an event listener for the navigation event DOMContentLoaded, before you start running any functions in the file.

Example:

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  /* All of your javascript code can execute here 
after the content on the pagehas loaded
})